# Codenameone SpanButton uiid not working

Tags: codenameone

I created a form initially with a normal Button and applied a uiid to the button.
This was working.
Now when I change the button to a SpanButton, the uiid stops working.
Is there anything that I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SpanButton` is a [composite component](http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2014/04/leading.html), this effectively means it is composed of several separate components and when you change its UIID you only change the UIID of the parent container and not the individual elements within it.

You need to also use `setTextUIID` & `setIconUIID`.